# debezium sql server connect getting error with auto.offset.reset=latest

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I have a problem with using Debezium. I searched on the internet but i cant find solution.
I'm using Windows 11 and Kafka 3.1

Here is my config values:

**Zookeepers.properties:**

> dataDir=C:/debezium/kafka/data/zookeper
>
> clientPort=2181
>
> maxClientCnxns=0
>
> admin.enableServer=false

**server.properties**

> broker.id=0
>
> listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
>
> num.network.threads=3
>
> num.io.threads=8
>
> socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
>
> socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
>
> socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
>
> num.partitions=1
>
> num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
>
> log.retention.hours=168
>
> log.segment.bytes=1073741824
>
> log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
>
> zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
>
> zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
>
> group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

**connect-standalone.properties**

> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
>
> key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>
> value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>
> key.converter.schemas.enable=true
>
> value.converter.schemas.enable=true
>
> offset.storage.file.filename=C:/debezium/kafka/connect/connect.offsets
>
> offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
>
> offset.reset=latest
>
> plugin.path=C:/debezium/kafka/connect

**and transaction_connector.properties**

> name=wallet-transaction-connector
>
> connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
>
> database.hostname= {MY_HOSTNAME}
>
> database.port=1433
>
> database.user=sa
>
> database.password= {SQL_PASSWORD}
>
> database.server.name= {REMOTE_SQL_SERVER}
>
> database.dbname=WalletDB
>
> table.include.list=dbo.TxOpenProvision
>
> database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
>
> database.history.kafka.topic=dbhistory.TxOpenProvision
>
> include.schema.changes=true

I run zookeeper, kafka and connect command below:

- Zookeper: .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
- Kafka: .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
- Connect: .\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties .\config\wallet_connector.properties

My SQL Server is remote server.

I'm getting this error and i cant resolve it. How can i solve this?

> ERROR [wallet-transaction-connector|task-0]
> WorkerSourceTask{id=wallet-transaction-connector-0} Task threw an
> uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will
> not recover until manually restarted
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:195)
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value earl²est
> for configuration auto.offset.reset: String must be one of: latest,
> earliest, none
> at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ValidString.ensureValid(ConfigDef.java:961)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:499)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:113)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:133)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.java:630)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:664)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:645)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:625)
> at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.storageExists(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:356)
> at io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseSchema.initializeStorage(HistorizedRelationalDatabaseSchema.java:80)
> at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorTask.start(SqlServerConnectorTask.java:81)
> at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:130)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSourceTask.java:225)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the logs, you have a special character `²` - `Invalid value earl²est`

In `connect-standalone.properties`, the config `offset.reset` is not a valid config...

Debezium is a producer (source connector), so setting `auto.offset.reset` doesn't make sense for it.

Also worth pointing out that Windows support for Kafka is very lacking; try using WSL2 instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree with you. I suppose there is a character set issue.. In the mean time how can i change this value? for example auto.offset.reset=latest

Comment: Like I said, that setting doesn't apply for Debezium, but you can read the official Kafka documentation on how to override client properties in the connector properties